# Would FeathersJS be suitable to synchronize an offline javascript database with a backend api

Tags: feathersjs

I want to be able to allow the user to work offline with a javascript database such as PouchDB or IndexDb to store records not just user data and then sync up to the server when online.

To that end FeathersJS said it could sit in the middle between a legacy api and the Feather's  client to handle real-time sync.

Does the real-time sync mean that Feathers is appropriate for use as a two way client to api synchronization with conflict resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that the default Feathers realtime sync does not handle offline storage and conflict resolution out of the box.

That said, there are a lot of resources for getting Feathers to accomplish this. I would start here:

https://feathersjs-offline.github.io/docs/

(Edited thanks to Yannick Marcon from a comment)

Comment: hmm these guides are dead - https://web.archive.org/web/20170928032217/https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/offline-first/strategies.html - seems there is no current active easy plug&play solution to this..

Comment: New documentation is here https://feathersjs-offline.github.io/docs/